# 502 Bad Gateway - Sendgrid PHP Mail Issue

Tags: php, email, nginx, sendgrid

I am getting 502 Bad Gateway error when I try to send email using Sendgrid's PHP library. I have attached the error log below,

```
502 Array ( 
[0] => HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
[1] => Server: nginx
[2] => Date: Thu, 27 Dec 2018 19:30:14 GMT
[3] => Content-Type: text/html
[4] => Content-Length: 166
[5] => Connection: keep-alive
[6] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io
[7] => Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
[8] => Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl
[9] => Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
[10] => X-No-CORS-Reason: 
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html
[11] =>
[12] => )
```

I don't know where I am wrong and I followed as per the documentation in SendGrid's website (Github as well). I have attached the code below what I used.

I have already tried possible troubleshooting found in other questions and issues in the GitHub repository of sendgrid-php.

```
<?php
  require("sendgrid/sendgrid-php.php");
  $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
  $email->setFrom("noreply@mydomain.com", "Leads");
  $email->setSubject($_POST['school'] . " - Appointment");
  $tos = [
    "support@mydomain.com" => "Support",
    $_POST['email'] => $_POST['name']
  ];
  $email->addTos($tos);
  $email->addContent("text/html", "<p><strong>Name:</strong> {$_POST['name']}</p>");
  $email->addContent("text/html", "<p><strong>Email:</strong> {$_POST['email']}</p>");
  $email->addContent("text/html", "<p><strong>Mobile:</strong> {$_POST['mobile']}</p>");
  $email->addContent("text/html", "<p><strong>School:</strong> {$_POST['school']}</p>");
  $email->addContent("text/html", "<p><strong>Count:</strong> {$_POST['count']}</p>");
  $email->addContent("text/html", "<p><strong>Gender:</strong> {$_POST['gender']}</p>");
  $sendgrid = new \SendGrid('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxAPIKEYxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
  }
?>
```

The email should be sent when the code is executed.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Check with SendGrid, if you have your country code wrong in your account settings, it might be preventing you from sending.

Comment: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/issues/650#issuecomment-408841711

Comment: Yes I saw it, but I don't know how to implement it. Can you help me on that @JeremyHarris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some weird issue with SendGrid. Sometimes, the API gets soft deleted automatically in the backend. To make the code work, I had to create a new API key and retry. And the solution worked.

> ***Note*** - Some issues in GitHub instructed to initialize a constructor with a from address, but that was not the actual issue.
>   The workaround is to create a new API key in the dashboard till
>   SendGrid investigates why the API is soft deleted so that the API call
>   returns an error.